# Compact letter display after Kruskal-Wallis-Test

Tags: r, plot, statistics, significant-digits, kruskal-wallis

I'm trying to evaluate some data for my thesis. I can use R to build a boxplot and conduct the statistical test just fine, and I can do the compact letter display manually... but this time I simply have too much data to do it this way. I'm plotting the distance travelled by different species against each other. I did find some manuals online telling me to use the cldList-function, like so:

```
PT = Data$res              
PT              
library(rcompanion)
cldList(P.adj ~ Comparison,
        Data = PT,
        threshold = 0.05)
```

But it seems the resulting table isn't right:
[1] Group      Letter     MonoLetter
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)

Obviously, I need the data grouped by species, but I thought I had already clarified this when conducting the Kruskal-Wallis-Test.
I'm fairly inexperienced with R, or programming in general, so I have no idea where the error is here. I'd apprechiate any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I agree with the comment above: please provide a reproducible example of your problem with (part of) (your) data like so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8830099 Until you do that, I can only point you in general directions like e.g. this tutorial: https://schmidtpaul.github.io/DSFAIR/compactletterdisplay.html

Comment: I am the author of the function.  Can you provide a reproducible example that shows the problem ?  (With toy data, so that anyone can run the example.)